# Processing a file line by line and parsing the line to get separate variables

Tags: c++, file, parsing, line

So I'm new to C++ and I am trying to take a file that looks like this:

```
0 A
1 B
2 C
3 D
4 E
```

I need to process this file line by line obviously and then in each line I need to take the two numbers from the line and put them in a map where the number is an ID # for a Node with a name that is a string so 0 would be the key for node A in my map.

I think I have the line by line part down but even that is a little rocky.

Here is what I have:

```
bool read_index(map<long, string> &index_map, string file_name)
{
    //create a file stream for the file to be read
    ifstream index_file(file_name);

    //if file doesn't open then return false
    if(! index_file.is_open())
        return false;

    string line;
    //read file
    while(! index_file.eof())
    {
        getline(index_file,line);
        stringstream ss(line);
        while(ss)
        {
            //process line?
        }
    }

    //file read
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are there spaces in your string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no spaces in the string, then you can ignore the newlines and just extract tokens:

```
void read_index(std::istream & infile, std::map<long, std::string> & index_map)
{
    long n;
    std::string token;

    while (infile >> n >> token) { index_map[n] = std::move(token); }
}
```

The error checking for opening the file should happen separately, before you call this function. Otherwise your function is doing Too Much.

If you have arbitrary strings, which may include whitespace, you need to use `getline`:

```
    for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        long n;
        std::string token;
        if (iss >> n >> std::ws && std::getline(iss, token))
        {
            index_map[n] = std::move(token);
        }
        else
        {
            // unparsable input line
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the benefit of line-based processing is that you can also handle invalid lines and skip over those. The first code that was purely token based stops once and for all as soon as it cannot recognize a token.

Comment: I do a lot of parsing, and I have to say that I prefer *always* do input linewise, it makes it a lot easier to handle errors correctly.

Comment: this is typically the kind of code that should take 2 lines. But when you get defensive, until full security you'll find yourself bloated with dozens of lines. http://danielroop.com/blog/2009/10/15/why-defensive-programming-is-rubbish/

Comment: @v.oddou: There's nothing "defensive" about this code. It is simply *correct*. I don't quite see the relevance of your comment or the link therein.

Comment: its totally relevant, your proposed second version is defensive, your first version is the clean 2 lines version.

Comment: @v.oddou: The two versions do different things, as I say in the answer. Neither is "defensive". They're just "programming". Maybe the word "error" is misleading, I changed it. When you're dealing with I/O you don't get to enforce preconditions. You simply have to deal with *any* input you get.

Comment: We must have a definition issue then. Because that is what I call being defensive. Not that it is bad, but it surely bloats things.

Comment: @v.oddou: "Defensive" means (at least in common parlance, and in that post you linked) that you don't trust your own program (e.g. you don't trust callers to respect the published API). *That* is indeed pointless bloat. (If you don't trust your own program or your programmers, you have bigger problems.) That is completely different from *consuming external data*.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `eof()`.  Try something more like this instead:

```
bool read_index(map<long, string> &index_map, string file_name)
{
    //create a file stream for the file to be read
    ifstream index_file(file_name);

    //if file doesn't open then return false
    if(!index_file)
        return false;

    string line;
    //read file
    while(getline(index_file, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        long n;
        std::string token;

        if (ss >> n >> token)
        {
            //process line
            index_map[n] = token; 
        }
        else
        {
            // error do something
        }
    }

    //file read?
    return !file.fail();
}
```

Comment: Is the first if really necessary?

Comment: Not strictly needed, no, but it does avoid wasting time an effort calling `getline()` and `fail()` if you know up front that they are going to fail.  Plus, it gives you an opportunity to log/debug which operation is failing.